# How to plot x int date values from array matplotlib correctly?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having an issue when trying to plot some of the date values into a matplotlib side by side bar graph.

I first define my Series x = new_df['month'] which contains the following values:

```
0,2021-01-01
1,2021-02-01
2,2021-03-01
3,2021-04-01
4,2021-05-01
5,2021-06-01
6,2021-07-01
7,2021-08-01
8,2021-09-01
9,2021-10-01
10,2021-11-01
11,2021-12-01
12,2022-01-01
13,2022-02-01
14,2022-03-01
15,2022-04-01
16,2022-05-01
17,2022-06-01
18,2022-07-01
19,2022-08-01
20,2022-09-01
21,2022-10-01
22,2022-11-01
```

After this I define the function to plot my graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def side_by_side_bar_chart(x, y, labels, file_name):

    width = 0.25 # set bar width
    ind = np.arange(len(x)) # Get the number of x labels
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

    # Get average number in order to set labels formatting
    ymax = int(max([mean(x) for x in y]))


    plt.xticks(ind, x) # sets x labels with values in x list (months)

    # These two lines format ax labels

    dtFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%y') # define the formatting
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dtFmt)

    plt.savefig("charts/"+ file_name + ".png", dpi = 300)
```

However, my x values are plotted as Jan 70 for all xticks:

[Wrong labeled x ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W2uE.png)

I suspect that this has something to do with formatting. The same is causing similar issues in a different part of the script where I use twin(x) for a side by side chart with a trendline on top and my values are plotted wrong in the graph:

[Wrong plotted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bGSh.png)

Does anybody have an idea how to fix these bugs? Thank you for your help in advance!

Pass the dates in the x array and plot all values correspondingly in the graphs.

Comment: What is `x`? You would receive more useful answers if you were to provide a [mre]. A [mre] contains everything that is needed for us to reproduce the problem. That includes the `import` and the data (some mock up data is enough). In your case `x`. And doesn't include any part of code irrelevant to the problem and not needed to reproduce it. For example, I doubt we really need the detail of how your compute `y` and `ylim`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @chrslg I removed the unnecessary code blocks and added the relevant data which in this case would be the x import.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your "x" is not a date. It is obviously a string. So formatter can't interpret it correctly.

Let's try to reproduce your problem (this is the kind of minimal reproducible example I was mentioning earlier) :

```py
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np # just to generate something to plot

# Generate a dummy set of 20 dates, starting from Mar 15 2020
dt=datetime.timedelta(days=31)
x0=[datetime.date(2020,3,1) + k*dt for k in range(20)]
x=[d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for d in x0] # This looks like your x: 20 strings 

# And some y to have something to plot
y=np.cumsum(np.random.normal(0,1,20)) # Don't overthink it, it is just 20 numbers :)

# Plot y vs x (x being the strings)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%y'))
plt.show()
```

Result
[image]

Now, solution for that is very simple: x must contains date, not strings.
From my example, I could just `plt.plot(x0,y)` instead of `x`, since `x0` is the list of dates from which I computed `x`. But if, as it appears, you only have the string available, you can parse them. For example, using `[d datetime.date.fromisoformat(d) for d in x]`.

Or, since you have already `pandas` at hand: `pd.to_datetime(x)` (it is not exactly the same date time, but both are understood by matplotlib)

```py
xx=pd.to_datetime(x)
plt.plot(xx,y)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%y'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that, without any action from me, it also stop printing all labels. That is because in the first case, matplotlib wasn't aware of any logical progression of `x` values. From its point of view, those where all just labels. And you can't, a priori, skip a label, since the reader could not guess what is between two labels separated by a gap (it seems obvious for us, since we know they are dates. But matplotlib doesn't know that. It is just as if x contained `['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'black', 'blue', ...]`. You would not expect every other label to be just arbitrarily skipped).

Whereas, now that we passed real dates to matplotlib, it is as if `x` was numerical: there is a logical progression of its values. Matplotlib knows it, and, more importantly, knows that we know it. So it is acceptable to just skip some to make the figure more readable: everybody knows what is between "Mar 20" and "May 20".

So, short answer: convert your string to dates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am still having some issues if I try to apply this to my use case when using this method. 

Based on your mini example if I would adapt the last part the labels default in Jan 70 even though I am using pd.to_datetime and plotting xx:

`# Plot y vs x (x being the strings)
xx=pd.to_datetime(x)
ind = np.arange(len(xx)) # Get the number of x labels
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.xticks(ind, xx) # sets x labels with values in x list (months)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%y'))
plt.show()`

Comment: You should not use both `xtickslabel` (which you are doing implicitly, when you path 2 parameters to `xticks`) and `DateFormatter` together. Called with 2 parameters, xticks sets only the position of the ticks, but also their label. And then the Formatter is irrelevant, since you forced the labels.

Comment: @yulesst You should either not call `xticks` at all, and let the matplotlib do the jobs (if you call plot with the dates `xx` as abscissa and what ever you want as ordinate, then it should choose where are the ticks correctly, and format the ticks itself using `DateFormatter`).

Comment: @yulesst Or, if you are unhappy with the location of the ticks, either define a tick locator, or specify the location with `xticks` (called with only one argument, the ticks position, and not the second one, their label).

Comment: Note that ticks positions for `xticks` should be in the abscissa scale. So, here, since abscissa are the dates (`xx`), it is also dates that you should pass to `xticks`

Comment: For example, if you want all dates to appear, simply `plt.xticks(xx)`. If you want a label every three dates, call `plt.xticks(xx[::3])`

Comment: Remark: it is the second time you post some codes with no plotting instruction at all. The first time I thought that you just omitted it (this is one of the reasons why I needed to recreate an example of mine).  But I am starting to wonder if you are not under the impression that `plt.xticks(...)` is the plotting instruction. It is not. It just says where are the labels on the x axis (and what they are, if 2 arguments are passed).

Comment: So, to try this, you need to plot something. Some `plt.plot(xx, data)`.

Comment: Thank you once again for all your comments, already very helpful. I am plotting bars in my chart, I did not include this because I wanted to keep it minimum. I was using `ind = np.arange(len(xx))` to get the numpy array values of my dates in x and then I was using plt.xticks(ind,xx) to label my my x values but ass pero your suggestion plt.xticks (xx) or leaving plt.xticks out both leave my labels at `Jan 70` even though I used `xx=pd.to_datetime(x)` to make sure that my xx values are of type datetime.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that if I use the ind values to plot my bars as xticks I cannot later tell matplot to replace the xticks label with my date values and at the same time change them to the taret format using DataFormatter...